# Push notification to a specific user with React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am new at mobile development and I choose React native, but I want to send remote push notification to a specific user. Can I use this library: react-native-push-notification ? there is a complete tutorial for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use this library https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm to connect your application with firebase, Then all you have to do is to log the device token that enable you to push notification for this device only with firebase

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no tutorial for that ?

Comment: The library Readme section describes how you can install it and include examples as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the UUID of each user and then you can use axios to send push notification to those users.

```
export const sendNotificationFirebaseAPI = async (
  token: string,
  title: string,
  body: string,
  data?: object,
) => {
  if (token != '') {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `key=${GOOGLE_FCM_KEY}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    const bodyToSend = JSON.stringify({
      to: token,
      notification: {
        title,
        body,
      },
      data,
    })
    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        headers: headers,
        data: bodyToSend,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      return { err }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps you!

See google firebase documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc

Answer (score 0):

Check [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage).
Section: Cloud Messaging.